# What is the fastest way to get from Mineralnye Vody to Kislovodsk by bus?

Tags: buses, caucasus, caucasian-mineral-waters

There are two intercity bus stations in Mineralnye Vody:

- Avtovokzal №2 (Bus station №2 - address: Gagarina st. 98)
- Novyi Avtovokzal (New bus station - address: Sovetskaya st. 97)

Buses from Mineralnye Vody to Kislovodsk are leaving only from "Novyi Avtovokzal" station in the evening. But it is only concerning regular buses:

[image]

But there could be minibuses (a.k.a "marshrutka") that leave when they are full. Do they exist? Where do they leave from for Kislovodsk? Do they operate in the evening?

What is the fastest way to get from Mineralnye Vody to Kislovodsk by bus (minimize waiting time)? Especially in the evening 20:00-22:00.

**UPDATE (oct. 2017):** Didn't have possibility to try bus. I took a taxi from Mineralnye Vody airport to Mineralnye Vody train station the price is 200 rub (plus 170 rub. suburb train to Kislovodsk). And on the way back I took a taxi from Kislovodsk to Mineralnye Vody airport, the price was 800 rub.

Comment: May I ask what Website you've screenshotted? Been looking for sites with Russian bus Services for ages

Comment: @Coke , there is no anything like "All-Russian Centralized Bus Services Cite", you should search for local information on the web, and there is high possibility that there is no info or it is out of date. Sorry. The screenshot is from https://www.avtovokzaly.ru , hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

The best way (price/speed/quality) I have found is [minibus transfer](http://kmv-transfer.ru/).

They have reception desk at the airport, and you can also call them to book a seat for the transfer back to airport.

The price (from Mineralnye Vody to Kislovodsk) is 300 rub. (on nov.2017) And it takes about an hour to get from one place to another.